# i want to show hide element by using dynamically generated class

Tags: jquery, soundmanager2

I want to show / hide the parent element with respect to the class in its childs has.
Here is what i want.

```
    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('mp3/coins.mp3');?>" title="hello" class="sm2_button" id="song1">play</a> Dear Yesterdays </p>
    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('mp3/fancy-beer-bottle-pop.mp3');?>" title="hello" class="sm2_button" id="song2">play</a> song 2</p>
    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('mp3/coins.mp3');?>" title="hello" class="sm2_button" id="song1">play</a> Dear Yesterdays </p>
    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('mp3/fancy-beer-bottle-pop.mp3');?>" title="hello" class="sm2_button" id="song2">play</a> song 2</p>

       <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.play p').hide();
        $('.play p:first').show();
    $('.play p a').each(function(){
    var attr = $(this).attr('class');
    var cls = attr.split(' ');  
    if(cls[1]=='sm2_playing' || cls[1]=='sm2_paused')
    {
        // display none to all .play p tags except the one with those classes sm2_playing or sm2_paused
        }
    });



    });
    </script>
```

please help me.
I am using soundmanager2. And i want to play songs one after another while only displaying the playing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery will not do what you are trying to do for future objects.

Rather than using `show()`/`hide()`, you can just simply use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` in conjunction with your CSS:

**CSS**

```
.play p
{
    display: none;
}

.play p.sm2_playing, .play p.sm2_paused
{
    display: block;
}
```

So then when you do `$(this).addClass('sm2_playing')` the element will show, and `$(this).removeClass('sm2_playing sm2_paused')` the element will hide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dynamically generating class or any object then you can't directly use that object. For such classes and objects you have to bind the events. Please refer JQuery bind [here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).